# Is there a way to add type definition globally in TypeScript 2+?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, typescript, definitelytyped

I have a bunch of simple `.ts` files. **NOT projects** (i.e. standalone .ts scripts).
They use some node.js functionality.
TypeScript and node type definitions are installed via

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g @types/node
```

Problem: on windows I can run `tsc foo.ts` with no problems. It transpiles .ts to .js just fine.
But on Ubuntu 16.04 it gives me `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'`, `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'` and etc.
Even if add `/// <reference types="node" />` to the top of `foo.ts` or add `--types node` switch to tsc I get `error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'`.

It looks like installing some types globally works fine in Windows but not on Ubuntu, so I'm assuming that this is not by design.
So is there a way to install them globally? Or more precisely: to reference globally installed type definitions on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to manually specify the `typeRoots` with the path leading to there npm installed global packages.
Like so: `tsc --typeRoots /usr/lib/node_modules/@types` (you can get the path for your system via `npm root -g`).

Still not sure why it looks them up without any special work on Windows and doesn't on Ubuntu. Can't tell if it's a bug and if it is then in which version.

Comment: I had to set `typeRoots` to the `<global npm folder>\@types` (`npm root -g`) in my `tsconfig.json` on Windows in order to make my globally installed (`npm i -g @types/node`) types work.